# Broken image in Chrome but all good in Firefox

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox

I have social media icons in a block in footer. Here is the very simple code :

```
<p style="text-align:center">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/mypage" target="_blank"><img src="/sites/default/files/pictures/Iconfb100.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="http://twitter.com/mypage" target="_blank"><img src="/sites/default/files/pictures/Icontw100.png"></a>
</p>
```

Working on localhost, it goes well on Firefox, but displays broken image icon in Chrome. I've deleted alt attribute, but still.
Just can't understand why.

Firefox displays :
[Firefox ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJW8C.jpg)

Chrome displays :
[Chrome broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aiRY.jpg)

Anyone Knows how to fix this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may try

```
<p style="text-align:center">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/mypage" target="_blank"><img src="sites/default/files/pictures/Iconfb100.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="http://twitter.com/mypage" target="_blank"><img src="sites/default/files/pictures/Icontw100.png"></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Swee Hong, I've already tried without the first slash in relative path. But if so I have also broken image in Firefox.

Comment: Sorry Swee Hong. Following your advice, I've deleted the slash. I have then the same result on both browsers, displays in home page but not in view pages. It appears to be a path problem related to Drupal. Thank you